# How can I check if a Player is already in another table/room? - Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a table/dictionary called: `Rooms` and when a client wants to join a room I check if the room UIDs match: `Rooms[i]["UID"] == Data`, if the UIDs match I check if the player is already in the room, if not I add the player to the the specific room they want to join, but I'm having some issues.

```
local Rooms = {
    [1] = {
        ["Name"] = "test1",
        ["Players"] = {},
        ["UID"] = game:GetService("HttpService"):GenerateGUID(true)
    },
    [2] = {
        ["Name"] = "test2",
        ["Players"] = {},
        ["UID"] = game:GetService("HttpService"):GenerateGUID(true)
    }
}
```

```
RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, Key, Data)
    if Key == "Join" then
        for i = 1, #Rooms do
            if Rooms[i]["UID"] == Data then
                if #Rooms[i]["Players"] > 0 then
                    for a = 1, #Rooms[i]["Players"] do
                        if Rooms[a]["Players"][a] == Player then
                            print("You are already in the room")
                        else
                            RemoteEvent:FireClient(Player, "Success")
                            table.insert(Rooms[a]["Players"], Player)
                        end
                    end
                else
                    RemoteEvent:FireClient(Player, "Success")
                    table.insert(Rooms[i]["Players"], Player)
                end             
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Now the problem is that my code lets the player join both rooms. For instance: Player joins room `[1]` and tries to join the room `[1]` again, it prints: `You are already in the room`; this is working perfectly! **But the problem is that when the player wants to move to room `[2]` it doesn't check if the player is already in a different room.**

**TL;DR:**

- **Player joins room [1].**
- Output: Player joined room [1].
- **Player joins room [1] again.**
- Output: You are already in the room.
- **Player joins room [2].**
- Output (MISTAKE): **Player joined room [2].**

**The player is not supposed to join room [2] because they haven't left room [1], but how can I check if the player is in a different room?**

Comment: What isn't working in this code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, Key, Data)
    if Key == "Join" then
        local targetRoomNum = nil
        for i, room in pairs(Rooms) do
            if room["UID"] == Data then
                targetRoomNum = i
            end

            for _, playerInRoom in pairs(room["Players"]) do
                if playerInRoom == Player then
                    print("You are already in a room")
                    return
                end
            end
        end
        
        if targetRoomNum then
            RemoteEvent:FireClient(Player, "Success")
            table.insert(Rooms[targetRoomNum]["Players"], Player)
        else
            print("No room found")
        end  
    end
end)
```